# Python : method resolution order of old-style (or classic) and new-style objects

Tags: python, oop, class, object

I have read a lot about Objects in Python Documentation which differentiates these two at some point like:

- Old-style instances, independently of their class, are implemented with a single built-in type, called instance.
- A new-style class is neither more nor less than a user-defined type.

Could anyone explain to me more on this **"old-style (or classic) and new-style."**

I can not figure out what this line is trying to say :

*"For new-style classes, the method resolution order changes dynamically to support cooperative calls to super()".*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Old class style:

```
class BaseClass:
    def m1(self):
        return 1

class MyClass(BaseClass):
    def m1(self):
        return BaseClass.m1(self)
```

New class style:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def m1(self):
        return 1

class MyClass(BaseClass):
    def m1(self):
        return super(MyClass, self).m1()
```

They are a lot of possibilities using new classes styles, like:

- `super(classname, ...).method()` instead of `parentclassname.method(...)`. The parent method is now determined from MRO (before, it was determined by you).
- `__slots__` is a new feature that can prevent to add a dict() in your object and allocate the memory only for the attribute in `__slots__`
- python properties (`@property`, `property()`...) is working only on new classes styles.

About MRO, check the document [The Python 2.3 Method Resolution Order](http://www.python.org/getit/releases/2.3/mro/). Before 2.2, the implementation was:

> depth first and then left to right

while the new one is C3, much more complicated but handle various case that the previous one didn't handle correctly (check the [Samuele Pedroni post on the python mailing list](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2002-October/029035.html)).

Comment: I See, now i can link may thing with your explanation, Thanks a lot and Code snippet make it easy to understand. MRO I read it Same link. Thanks again.